# Derivation of Arc Length Formula in Generalized Coordinates

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Let’s say I have a metric tensor

$$ds^2 = \sum_i\sum_j g_{i,j} dx^i dx^j$$

and a parameterized curve $x^i(t)$

where $x^i$ is the $i$th coordinate index, $g_{i,j}$ is the lowering operator, and $ds$ is the metric length.

I know that to calculate the arc length we integrate both sides of this formula:
$$d\ell = \sqrt{\sum_i\sum_j g_{i,j} \frac{dx^i}{dt}\frac{dx^j}{dt} }dt$$

But I don’t quite understand the derivation of this formula. The time derivative of $x^i$ gives the vector tangent to the curve, and I can intuit that the right-hand side is essentially an infintesimal length of the tangent vector over $dt$, but I’d like a more rigorous derivation/proof.

I thought maybe the trick was to take the time derivative of $ds^2=\ldots$ but that doesn’t seem to work.

Thank you.

Comment: This is almost by definition. The length of a curve $t\mapsto x(t)$ is defined as the integral of $\|\dot{x}(t)\|$, and if $x(t)$ is described in coordinates as $(x^1(t),\ldots, x^n(t))$, then $\|\dot{x}(t)\|^2 = g_{ij}(x(t))\dot{x}^i(t)\dot{x}^j(t)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a curve parametrized by the interval $[0,T]$. Then, the length of that curve $\gamma(t)$, as a function of $t$,  is given by $$\ell(t)=\int_0^t ||\gamma'(\tau)||d\tau$$
where the prime denotes differentiation and the lines denote the norm of the velocity vector. Now, what is this norm? It can be many things, but, in general, in a metric vector space (and in specific in a tangent space to a manifold equipped with a metric) we are interested in the vector norm which is induced by the inner product. What is the inner product in our case? It's given by the metric tensor! So the norm is in fact
$$||\gamma'||=\sqrt{g(\gamma',\gamma')}$$
Now, all you have to do is diferentiate the earlier expression for the length. Doing so yields
$$l'(t)=\sqrt{g(\gamma',\gamma')}$$
which is the same as saying $$dl=\sqrt{g_{ij}\frac{dx^i}{dt}\frac{dx^j}{dt}}dt$$
if you recall the definition of the differential of a function and expand $g(\gamma',\gamma')$ out in components.

Your intuition was of course correct, the rate of change of length is of course the norm of the velocity, as it should; and everything sorts itself out as long as you remember (and see why it is good) the definition of the length of a curve.

Comment: So it just comes from integrating the velocity norm and the definition of inner products under a metric tensor?

Comment: @user2610818 Yes that is right. If you were in a cartesian space with an euclidean metric you would have $$dl=\sqrt{\gamma' \cdot \gamma'}dt$$ instead. Since the metric is formally the inner product in the tangent space to the surface, where the velocity lives, it's a natural generalization of the euclidean formula